# (Why) Should I choose Unity 3 or Cocos2d (or something third) for my app?

Tags: html, cocos2d-iphone, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

My colleague and me made an HTML 5 iPad game ( http://braille.gandzo.com/ ) and we would like to upgrade it, and our framweork is not enoguh, for what we want. Some of the things we would change are: graphics update, animations/"effects", multi-player, achievements and so on. The game would stay 2d. Now, as far as I understand, both Unity and Cocos would be good for this task, with Unity having the advantage of being multi-platform.

What I want to know is are there unknown qualites/"flaws" to these two programs which would influence my decision (maybe even by choosing something else). Examples that come to mind are "Unity is too complicated/has too much unneeded options/hoops because it's made with 3d in mind" or "Cocos is significantly more suited for 2d games".

Comment: Bit of a subjective question. I would vote for cocos2d "because it's what I use"

Comment: From another place I asked: Just a note to everyone. This question isn't THAT subjective. You can make a pretty objective decision on this if you have experience in both platforms. Simply put, one tool is built for his task, the other isn't. The question could be reworded to seem less subjective, but it shouldn't be voted down as it's a pretty valid question IMO.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter btw. I just couldn't provide an objective answer.

Comment: Haha, no problem, at least someone is looking at this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the game is pretty much in 2d... I would suggest for cocos2d. I am working on cocos2d for past 1 and half years... I don't have experience in Unity but ya my colleagues who used to work on Unity had so many problems with animation, texturing etc.
BTW I was not able to play you game on my Chrome. :)

Comment: Forgot to mention: if you're on the PC, controls are A,S,D, J,K,L